# Prove that $D'_n=\langle x^2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, derived-subgroup

I want to check if my solution to one problem from my group theory course is valid. The problem is:

> Given $D_n=\{x^iy^j:0\leq i<n,0\leq j<2\}$, prove that $D'_n=\langle x^2\rangle$.

My attempt is:

Given two different elements $g=x^ay^b$ and $h=x^cy^d$ (it's clear that $g,h\in D_n$). We calculate its commutator:

$$[g,h]=x^ay^bx^cy^dy^{-b}x^{-a}y^{-d}x^{-c}$$
Using that $yx^iy=x^{-i}$ (I'll go almost straight to the result avoiding the operations) we get that

$$[g,h]=x^ax^{-c}y^by^dy^{-b}y^{-d}x^ax^{-c}=x^{2a-2c}=(x^2)^{a-c}\in \langle x^2\rangle.$$
So this proves that, $\forall g,h\in D_n$, $[g,h]\in\langle x^2\rangle$, so from this we conclude that
$$\boxed{D'_n=\langle x^2\rangle}$$
Is my solution valid? If not, why? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: small tip: in mathjax, instead of using $<$ and $>$ for group presentations, use \langle and \rangle, which look like $\langle$ and $\rangle$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for the tip! I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you showed that $D_n'\subseteq \langle x^2\rangle$. But what about the other direction? It is easy though, because $x^2=[x,y]\in D_n'$, and so $\langle x^2\rangle\subseteq D_n'$.

By the way, another way to see that $D_n'\subseteq\langle x^2\rangle$ is to note that $D_n/\langle x^2\rangle$ has either order $2$ or order $4$, depends if $n$ is even or odd. But in either case, $D_n/\langle x^2\rangle$ is abelian, and so $\langle x^2\rangle$ contains all the commutators of the group.